# using ng-repeat to print out all items sorted by different categories into rows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So, i've managed to print out items from a list in a very messy way that is desperately in need of refactoring

say I have an array of objects like

```
var items = [{name: "toaster", price: 10, category: "appliance"},{name: "spade", price: 5, category: "tool"},{name: "hoe", price: 5, category: "tool"},{name: "microwave", price: 10, category: "appliance"}]
```

Using ng-repeat, I would like to print out the name and price of each item into a row according to category without having to have a lot of messy code.  Currently my code looks similar to this:

```
<section class="container">
      <div class="row"> 
    <h3>Tool</h3>
        <ul class="list-group col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | filter: { category:'tool'}">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <p>Name: {{item.name}} </p>
            <p>Price: £{{item.price}} </p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </section>

      <section class="container">
      <div class="row"> 
    <h3>Appliances</h3>
        <ul class="list-group col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | filter: { category:'appliance'}">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <p>Name: {{item.name}} </p>
            <p>Price: £{{item.price}} </p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </section>
```

Is there anyway to make this a lot less messier?  Would I have to presort the objects into different arrays in the controller?  Or is there a better way to use the filterBy method?

**EDIT**

Ideally, the resultant html should look like this

```
<section class="container">
          <div class="row"> 
        <h3>Appliance</h3>
          <ul>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <p>Name: Toaster </p>
                <p>Price: £10</p>
              </li>
             <li class="list-group-item">
                <p>Name: Microwave</p>
                <p>Price: £10</p>
              </li>
            </ul>

           <h3>tool</h3>
 <ul>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <p>Name: Hoe</p>
                <p>Price: £5</p>
              </li>
             <li class="list-group-item">
                <p>Name: Spade</p>
                <p>Price: £5</p>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
      </section>
```

It should look something like that

Comment: may be you can add another ng-repeat on container: `category in [['Tool', 'tool'],['Appliances','appliance']]` and use `category[1]` in filter

Comment: Tool and Appliances are just h3 tags, not relevant to ng-repeat, just hardcoded otherwise each list element has the category printed above it but I'll try this out now

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood the question correctly, what you are actually looking for is that you want to sort the data according to the 'category' key.

For sorting purposes you are suppose to use 'orderBy' filter provided by angularjs .

```
<section class="container">
      <div class="row"> 
    <h3>Sort By Category</h3>
        <ul class="list-group col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | orderBy: 'category'">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <p>Name: {{item.name}} </p>
            <p>Price: £{{item.price}} </p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </section>
```

This should do the trick.

For more information you can refer to this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: Close, but I would want a Category title put at the beginning of every new category list, is this possible with the orderBy method?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML response which you expect ?

Comment: it would looks like <br/>     
Appliance:
   name: Toaster,
   price: 5,
   name: microwave,
  price:5,

Tools:
  name: spade,
  price: 10,

name: hoe,
price 10,


or something like that, sorry about the indentation, i really cant get it to work properly in these mini comments

Comment: You can edit the question you have asked, you can provide it there. It is difficult to understand the expected HTML

Comment: Ok I've made the changes, sorry for the confusion